# Triggering Input Buttons within iFrames with a loop from a prompt (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dom

I am an avid user of stackoverflow, I can always count on the millions of posts to find the solution, but somehow I have gotten stuck here, I am probably just tired ha ha.

Busy with some code to assist in posting our companies jobs to some paid for job portals we use. (already done that code)

With limited access to the pages in our CRM. This is the situation.

- I can edit the JavaScript in the top level parent
- Inside the parent is an iframe 'app_win' and inside that is an iframe 'other_frame'
- My code in a top-level div prompts the user for total_jobs after clicking the following input
  (input onclick="find_other_frame();" value="postjobs")
- Simulates clicking the 3 buttons in 'other_frame'
- Simulates clicking the next buttons in 'app_winn'

Where I am stuck. 
- If I add an alert in each iteration the code works great but without an alert it executes only once.

```
<script language="JavaScript">


            function find_other_frame() {
                var total_jobs = Number(prompt("How Many Jobs are Currently open?"));
                var i = 0;
                while (i < total_jobs) {
                    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('app_win');
                    var innerDoc1 = iframe1.contentDocument || iframe1.contentWindow.document;

                    var iframe2 = innerDoc1.getElementById('other_frame');
                    var innerDoc2 = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document;

                    innerDoc2.getElementById('button1').click(); //job site 1
                    innerDoc2.getElementById('button2').click(); //job site 1
                    innerDoc2.getElementById('button3').click(); //job site 1

                    // and then next job - basically a button called next job
                    innerDoc1.querySelector("#smartnav > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)").click(); 

                    i++;

                };
            };
</script>
```

Why does it take javascript pause execution to allow the entire loop to run. Is it because when the next button is clicked in 'app_win' the iframe is reloaded and the code can't find 'other_frame' - the sub iframe in 'app_win"?

**Feel free to shout at me if its something simple.**

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Comment: No no errors in the console. 
What about a delay when the code is run - to allow the page to load fully? Document.ready

Comment: Ok I think I know where I might be going wrong [link](http://scottiestech.info/2014/07/01/javascript-fun-looping-with-a-delay/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution - if you think it needs improving then please let me know.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

            function find_other_frame_open()    {
                var total_jobs = Number(prompt("How Many Jobs would you like to Post?"));
                (function theLoop (i) {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('app_win');
                    var innerDoc1 = iframe1.contentDocument || iframe1.contentWindow.document;

                    var iframe2 = innerDoc1.getElementById('other_frame');
                    var innerDoc2 = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document;

                    innerDoc2.getElementById('wpv_1290391').click();
                    innerDoc2.getElementById('wpv_1290393').click();
                    innerDoc2.getElementById('wpv_1290340').click();
                    innerDoc1.querySelector("#smartnav > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)").click();
                    if (--i) { 
                      theLoop(i);
                    }
                  }, 4000); //4 second delay
                })(total_jobs);
            };

            function find_other_frame_close()   {
                var total_jobs = Number(prompt("How Many Jobs Need to Be Closed?"));
                (function theLoop (i) {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('app_win');
                    var innerDoc1 = iframe1.contentDocument || iframe1.contentWindow.document;

                    var iframe2 = innerDoc1.getElementById('other_frame');
                    var innerDoc2 = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document;

                    innerDoc2.getElementById('thePnetClose').click();                       
                    innerDoc1.querySelector("#smartnav > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)").click();
                    if (--i) {
                      theLoop(i);
                    }
                  }, 4000); //4 second delay
                })(total_jobs);
            };              
</script>
```